# No clue why I'm getting a illegal character error

Tags: java

For some reason in the testEmployee method I am getting weird error messages saying illegal character.

I've looked at the code but can't find anything syntactically wrong with it.

Any help would be great thanks!

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import ttp.Cache;
import ttp.DataException;
import ttp.EmployeeDAO;
import ttp.Employee;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author ericrea
 */
public class Tester {

    public Tester() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    // TODO add test methods here.
    // The methods must be annotated with annotation @Test. For example:
    //
    // @Test
    // public void hello() {}

//    /** Test the Skeleton BO/DAO */
//    @Test
//    public void TestSkeleton() throws Exception {
//    Skeleton s = SkeletonDAO.getInstance().create(“skeleton1”);
//     s.save();
//
//    // since skeleton1 is in the Cache, this tests reading from the cache
//    Skeleton s2 = SkeletonDAO.getInstance().read(“skeleton1”);
//    assertSame(s, s2);
//
//    // now clear the cache (you’d never do this in the real world)
//    // then we can test reading from the database
//    Cache.getInstance().clear();
//    Skeleton s3 = SkeletonDAO.getInstance().read(“skeleton1”);
//    assertEquals(s.getId(), s3.getId());
//    //assertEquals(s.getSomething(), s3.getSomething());
//
//    // keep testing more methods, BOs, and DAOs
//     }//TestSkeleton
//    //5. Right-click the file and run the file. You’ll see it test. It will obviously have errors 
//    //because Skeleton isn’t a real BO/DAO.
//    //6. Note in the above code the “assertEquals” methods. That is how you test that two things are equals.

    @Test
    public void TestEmployee() throws DataException {
    Employee e = EmployeeDAO.getInstance().create(“Employee1”);
    e.save();

    // since skeleton1 is in the Cache, this tests reading from the cache
    Employee e2 = EmployeeDAO.getInstance().read(“Employee1”);
    assertSame(e, e2);

    // now clear the cache (you’d never do this in the real world)
    // then we can test reading from the database
    Cache.getInstance().clear();
    Employee e3 = EmployeeDAO.getInstance().read(“Employee1”);
    assertEquals(e.getId(), e3.getId());
    assertEquals(e.getName1(), s]e3.getName1());

    }
```

Comment: whoops that was an accident. DELETE javascript tag

Comment: Thanks to your code, I was able to see why I was getting an "Illegal Start of Expression".  Dummy me, I was trying to use assert.assertEquals.  I removed the first assert and I stopped getting that error.  Duh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to use 'fancy' quotes (`“`) instead of normal ones (`"`)

PS If **Matt** is right, please do not use Word to edit your programs. There're lots of IDEs, but even Notepad would be easier.

Comment: Yup, that would be another problem. Must be editing with Word or something... +1

Comment: Thank you! Still getting a "reached end of file while parsing" error on the last "}", any ideas?

Comment: received starter code from a class website so that was probably the reason!

Comment: @Eric You're missing closing `}` for class definition. BTW, if you were using an IDE, you wouldn't have to ask us what's wrong. E.g., this one http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: I use netbeans, but I received the starter code from class website like I mentioned. Thanks everyone. How do I give you points for helping me????

Comment: @Eric: If you can, upvote all responses that have helped. Accept the answer that helped "most", or is most-correct. Looking at the original question (illegal character), the correct answer is Nikita's.

Comment: Ok thanks you guys! I'm relatively new to stack overflow so thanks for the help and the instructions:)

Answer (score 3):

The fragment

```
s]e3.getName1()
```

(last line) doesn't look right: remove the "s]" fragment.

**Edit**: You are also missing the closing parenthesis for the class at the end of the code.

Comment: thanks for spotting that, not fixing the errors though. Here is where they are:

Comment: Employee e = EmployeeDAO.getInstance().create(“Employee1”);, Employee e2 = EmployeeDAO.getInstance().read(“Employee1”);, Employee e3 = EmployeeDAO.getInstance().read(“Employee1”);, and I'm getting a "reached end of file while parsing error on the last "}""

Comment: I guess this is the problem Nikita spotted.